# How to check if a string is a listitembutton?

Tags: python, kivy

How do I check if a string is in a list item button which was inputted and return the buttons that has the string? I am trying to access it through the list adapter data, I am not receiving errors but its not yielding the results I want

Here is some code

```
    def sortlist(self):
        if any(self.search_string1.text and self.search_string2 in s for s in self.manager.ids.project_list_screen.project_list.adapter):

            sm.current = "placements"

            return self.manager.ids.project_list_screen.project_list.adapter.handle_selection(self.search_string1.text, self.search_string2.text)
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Your `if` statement will evaluate `self.search_string2 in s for s in self.manager.ids.project_list_screen.project_list.adapter` to produce a Boolean. That result will be the right hand side of the Boolean `and` with `self.search_string1.text` being the left hand side. Perhaps that is not what you want?

Comment: the if statement is not the problem I want to access data in a list of item buttons and I don't know how to access the data inside them, if I put a text in the data section of ListAdapter(data=[],  cls=main.ProjectListButton), it shows if the strings are in that data but im not trying to access the data section, im trying to access the text that are in the list of buttons

Comment: Please post a [mcve].